# Result of Import-CSV different depending on where I run script

Tags: powershell

Okay, I'll try to explain this well.

I have a powershell script, that's been running wonderfully in vscode, but now that I'm trying to run it in an actual powershell window, it seems to have changed the way it's importing the csv. Here's the relevant part of the script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory,
    Position=0)]
    [string[]]
    $ComputerList
)

$ComputerList = Import-Csv -Path $ComputerList
$ComputerList
```

So, when I run the script in vscode with .\Input\ExampleList.csv as the ComputerList param, I get the following output as I would expect:

```
Name
----
Server1
Server2
Server3
Server4
Server5
Server6
Server7
Server8
Server9
Server10
Server11
Server12
```

However, if I run the exact same script, from the exact same location, with the exact same invocation, but from a powershell window, I get the following.

```
@{Name=Server1}
@{Name=Server2}
@{Name=Server3}
@{Name=Server4}
@{Name=Server5}
@{Name=Server6}
@{Name=Server7}
@{Name=Server8}
@{Name=Server9}
@{Name=Server10}
@{Name=Server11}
@{Name=Server12}
```

What am I doing wrong here? It's probably obvious but I'm stumped at this point. I'm using the same version of powershell in both instances, $PSVersionTable returns:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.5
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.5
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22000
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it looks like I was able to fix the problem as I was typing this by changing:

```
$ComputerList = Import-Csv -Path $ComputerList
```

to

```
$ComputerList = Import-Csv -Path $ComputerList -Header "Name"
```

What I don't understand is why it worked fine in vscode but not in normal powershell. Mind you, this worked inside and out when the path to import-csv was hardcoded and not brought in with a param.

Comment: Upon looking at the code again, I'm realizing I was using the same var for the path to the CSV, and for the generated list, which I'm sure was causing problems. Upon changing the code to separate out the vars, the problem went away without needing to use the header arg.